# tmux key-binding doesn't work over ssh

Tags: macos, ssh, tmux

I am using iterm2 on a Mac, the tmux key binding works well if I start tmux locally. In particular, the Alt + arrow to switch panes.

```
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D
```

However, the key binding no longer works when I do ssh login (to a Linux box). Any idea how to fix it? TIA

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Meta key not working. Did you find a fix?